# Blackberry JDE generating bad .jad file (does not match compiled .cod file)

Tags: java, blackberry, jde

I Have a BB application that gets compiled into 3 siblings cod file. ( actualy one cod fil contaning 3 sub cod files).

```
app.cod
|--app.cod
|--app-1.cod
|--app-2.cod
```

which is normal.

the jad refers to those 3 inner .cod files.

Now I have add some feature to my app, it is getting a little bit bigger.
the jad now refers to 4 inner .cod files.
but there is still 3 inside the app.cod that is generated.

so I now still have

```
app.cod
|--app.cod
|--app-1.cod
|--app-2.cod
```

but with the jad referring to app.cod, app-1.cod, app-2.cod, AND app-3.cod.

this is causing OTA download to fail with the following error:

> 907 invalid COD HTTP Error 404 : not
>   found

what is wrong the my compiled program? is it a bug from the JDE?

I am using JDE 4.5

Comment: I also faced the same problem. I deleted all lines in jad file beginning with RIM-COD-SHA1, RIM-COD-URL etc and then build the project again. It correctly updated the jad file!!

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that somehow the jad builder got confused, and maybe it gained a little more space in compression than it expected?  either add another image to you application to make it a little larger or you can use

updateJad.exe app.jad

this will update the sizing of the jad file to match everything.

the file is located in the /bin folder with javaloader and other files of your JDE install.

Comment: That is what I was doing (using the updateJad.exe) but event this tool is complaining that it can not find the last app-3.cod file.

Comment: hmm thats really really strange.  How big is the phantom cod according to the jad?  I would say for now manually remove the cod, but that is not a good actual solution.  Or go with my "add another image" plan